# How to get coordinates of kml file android

Tags: android, gps, kml

I want to receive the coordinates of the points that are in the kml file.
I created a object that receives the coordinates but I can not find how to take them from the file.

An example of what has been done so far:
(The amount of points is 132, but I shortened it to be able to present here.)

Kml file:

```
<LinearRing>
                <coordinates>
                    34.79991805485883,32.070779943443,0
                    34.799829164854,32.07080649750882,0
                    34.79971023480251,32.07083335300256,0
                    34.79959122858838,32.07086022634235,0
                    34.79947508289758,32.07091343448649,0
                    34.79935881388468,32.07096669690968,0
                    34.79923664471844,32.07096729415576,0
                    34.79912177286835,32.07104658864036,0
                </coordinates>
<LinearRing>
```

In code:

```
   int i =0; 
   for (KmlContainer containers : kmlLayer.getContainers()) {
       poly[i] =new PointPoly(containers);
       i++;
     }
```

The code does not work.
Would appreciate help.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you got the String containing the coordinates.
(the text between the `<coordinates>` tag)
Then use

```
String[] coords3d = coordStr.split(" ");
```

to split into an array of lon,lat,altitude string.
Loop over that array and split each string with

```
String[] coordLatLonAltitude = coord.split(",");
```

to split into separate latitude, longitude and altitude values.

Comment: The problem that is I can not get the data from the kml file. After that I know what to do.

Comment: A kml is like an xml. If you cannot parse an xml file, you cannot parse a kml.

Comment: You have a text file in kml format. Either search in your programm for <coordinates> or learn how to parse a xml file. Orf you find a ready kmlParser software that gives you back an kml object which you iterate.

Comment: I asked a question because I could not find answers.

Comment: LEARN HOW TO READ IN  A XML FILE; google "parsing xml java"

Comment: I know how to read.
I have to take away information from the kml code
I have 132 points and I have to Put them in an array I want to do it in a smart way

Comment: If you have read the coordinates into a String starting with "34.79991805485883,32.070779943443,0 ..." containing all the coordinates you posted. then just parse the string like in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
for (KmlContainer c : kmlLayer.getContainers()) {
    for (KmlPlacemark p : c.getPlacemarks()) {
        KmlGeometry g = p.getGeometry();
        if (g.getGeometryType().equals("LineString")) {
            points.addAll((Collection<? extends LatLng>) g.getGeometryObject());
        }
    }
}
```

GeometryType can be different on your kml file, like "LinearRing". But basicaly this is working code for me.